# Entity Data Model Using EF is Getting Closed when trying to connect Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

m trying to add a ADO.Net Entity Data Model using Entity Framework 6 to a Net.Framework Class Library, but when I get to Step 3, when you choose the Framework version it immediately closes the wizard and my connection to my Oracle Database This is what it shows before it closes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3jV8.png)automatically.

I thought, there is some problem on installation of Oracle Developer Tools so I have uninstall and install it but still the problem persists.
And tried with change the version of EF, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework and ODAC.

I am using ODT - 19.3.3.0

Comment: Oracle connection are very sensitive to version of database and version of the driver.  The connection string needs to be modified of the driver is not installed.  Try downloading the driver : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html